# Connect JProgress Bar to an array to show progress of the tool

Tags: java, arrays, progress-bar

I've created a tool where I paste some data in a text area and this data is being split per lines by (\n) in an array.
My tool works perfect, I just need to connect this progress of the array to the progress bar so the user may know what's going on.
so if the array will have 10 lines the progress bar shall start from one and count till it reaches ten when the tool moves to the next line.
so I mean when it starts working on the array in position 0, the progress bar shall show 1, and when the array moved to position 1, progress bar shall show 2 .......

Here is an example of my code:

```
// Run button (start the search)
final JButton btn = new JButton("Run");
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            String getTextArea;
            getTextArea = textArea.getText();
            // converting the input to an array
            String[] arr = getTextArea.split("\\n");
            // clearing the text
            textArea_1.setText("");
            //line = arr.length;
            // looping for the input
                // doing something.....
            }   
            // end of for loop  
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Search was not completed due to bad connection, please try pressing run again or close the tool and reopen it");
        }
    }
});

// Creating the progress bar
JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
progressBar.setValue(0);
for(int z = 0; z <= line; z++) {
    progressBar.setValue(z);
    z = z + 1;
    progressBar.repaint();
}
progressBar.setBounds(364, 11, 139, 22);
contentPane.add(progressBar);
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've interpreted your question as how do I get the line number to be displayed instead of the percentage?

If that is the question, then you need to use the `JProgressBar`'s `setString(String s)` method as well as `setValue(int n)`

For example:

```
// Set up of the JProgressBar
final int MIN = 0;
final int MAX = 100;
JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(MIN, MAX);
progressBar.setStringPainted(true); // show the text on the progress bar
progressBar.setString("Loop no. " + MIN); // initial display

// Code to update the JProgressBar
for (int i=MIN; i<=MAX; i++) {
    progressBar.setValue(i);
    progressBar.setString("Loop no. " + i);
}
```

Personally I prefer to use an implementation of `BoundedRangeModel` when working with progress bars. Swing provides `DefaultBoundedRangeModel` which is good for most tasks.

Remember to use concurrency correctly in your implementation, otherwise your interface will be unrespsonive if the task is long. `SwingWorker` can assist you with this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Comment: Yes you got my point, I will try your suggestion and will let you know the result, thank you a lot